# Special Characters in FTP from Java in ZVM

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe, zos

I am trying to do FTP of files from IBM z/VM to my windows machine, but most of the files are **not** getting special characters.

All the special characters, i.e., characters which are in latin or greek are being replaced with junk.

I have checked in SO but there are no questions with the tag z/VM or questions with z/VM.

Could some one please help me in solving this issue ?

Any reference on this would also be helpful !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Today (oh happy day) you get to learn about [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)! It's always fantastic when people get to learn something new (or rather really really really old).

Comment: Did you declare text mode in FTP?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch :) I know of EBCDIC, but the problem is even if i set the command `ftp.sendCommand("site sbdataconn=(IBM-1140,ISO8859-1)");` in my code, it is still not returning special characters.

Comment: Is the FTP server reporting any problems with your SITE command?  If you just run your FTP at a command prompt, outside of your code, does it succeed or fail?  If it fails, what, if any, errors are reported?

Comment: Have you checked whether your original files are actually IBM-1140? Or whether the tool you use for viewing is acutally showing ISO8859-1?

Answer (score 0):

The FTP command in CMS has a "TRANSLATE" option.  E.g.
  ftp somehost (translate xxxxyyyy

where:
xxxx is the host (z/VM) code page you used to create the file.  E.g. 0037 or 1047 or 0924.

yyyy is the remote (workstation) code page that you want.   E.g. 0923 or 1252 [Western Windows]

FILELIST * TCPXLBIN *   will give you the list of possible combinations.  The default table will not correctly translate EBCDIC "extended characters".

I have some additional information at http://www.vm.ibm.com/devpages/altmarka/tcpip.html